# How to get data from one http request response and use as input for another http request

Tags: jmeter

In Jmeter test plan, I have too many http requests. One of this creates a new session every time when clicking the create button. After that other http request use that session id in URL.
How to get that session id when we call create button and put it into other request URL?

Comment: https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-load-testing-scenarios-jmeter-part-1-correlations

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a use-case for the [HTTP URL Re-writing Modifier](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_URL_Re-writing_Modifier), just provide your `session id` as the "Session Argument Name" and it should do the "magic" of hard-coded parameters substitution for you.

See [Using the HTTP URL Re-writing Modifier](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-http-url-re-writing-modifier) article for comprehensive explanation and real-life usage scenario if needed.